# Div bound to other div when browser window size changes

Tags: html, css

I have the following problem:
[image]

the speech bubble should always point on the eye, regardless of the browser window size.

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/8atxhLbm/13)

So far I have the following code:

```
<div class="container1">
    <div class="container2">
         <button class="eye"></button>
         <div class="speech-bubble">View</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

where

```
.container1 {
    text-align: center;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    width: 100%; }

.container1 > .container2 {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1;}

.speech-bubble {
    position: absolute;}
```

But this does not work and produces the above output.
What can I do to make it work? Please no jQuery solutions, since I use Angular.

**Edit**: If you omit the `text-align: center`, the code will achieve the desired effect. But not quite: I want to have the buttons centered! And still have the mentioned effect! How would I do that?

Comment: Just curious to ask is your question more related to CSS3 than other subjects you flagged?

Comment: you may need to override `speech-bubble` css

Comment: Speech bubble generated by http://html-generator.weebly.com/css-speech-bubble-generator.html

Comment: Please can you provide the full code that reproduces this issue.

Comment: Yes. The following does: http://jsfiddle.net/8atxhLbm/13/
However, I have found the error. It is the `text-align: center`. Omitting that it works as expected. Thank you for making me dig through this...

Comment: @Clawish Glad you got to the bottom of it, if you sorted this out yourself please consider posting an answer with your findings.

Comment: The proper way to do this involves putting the speech bubble within the button. In that way the speech bubble will always be positioned relative to the button in case of static, relative or even in the relative-absolute criteria. Or do you have a problem doing it this way, that you put the speech bubble outside the button? In that case, its a whole lot tougher. Comment if you need to know more or to let me know if this solved your problem...

Comment: Yes this would be a problem, since a click on the bubble should trigger something different than a click on the button. However, I managed to do it, see answer. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yup, I saw that. But did you try that on any other browser? 'Coz I think it worked only because of display: -webkit-box; and display: -webkit-flex; Just asking... Those are new to me anyway. Oz87's answer was the workaround I was talking about, but with a few more additional semantics changes.

Comment: Didn't test. For other browsers you might want to use `display: -moz-box;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to do it without much hackiness.
Change `.container2` to

```
.container1 > .container2 {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8atxhLbm/18/).

Comment: Could you please add more information about what you changed and why? Just code isn't very usefull for the asker, most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

did you mean something like this?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9Lm5bve0/)

Also with position absolute you don't have to use `left: (x amount)px or %;`. In some cases it is easier to use `right: (x amount)px or %;`. By the way, if you want to position an element absolute to it's parent element, the parent element also needs a position defined e.g.: `position: relative;`. If not, the absolute postioned element will look for the closest parent that has a position set other than the default value. Hope this helps.